# Replace JQuery Not working for text which having brackets

Tags: jquery

I am trying to replace some text '+32 (0)' with below code but its not working please help

```
<h2>We have +32 (0) on our farm</h2>
$("h2:contains('+32 (0)')").html(function(_, html) {
   return  html.replace(/(+32 (0))/g, '<span class="prefix">+32 (0)</span>')
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w5ze6/834/)**

Comment: `/(+32 (0))/g` is not the right way to write it. try `/\+32 \(0\)/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `(` and `)` by using `\` and you can [use `$&` to get matched text in replace pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

```js
$("h2:contains('+32 (0)')").html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/\+32 \(0\)/g, '<span class="prefix">$&</span>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>We have +32 (0) on our farm</h2>
```

Comment: how to do this for '+44' confusing with slash. pls help

Comment: @AnoopPranav : `(/\+44 \(0\)/g`

Comment: @ Pranav-C-Balan. I mean only for +44. with out '(0)'

Comment: @AnoopPranav : then use `/\+44/g`

Comment: @AnoopPranav : glad to help :)